# ForEach and Facelets

Tags: java, foreach, jstl, facelets

My managed bean :

```
public List<String> getLiQuickNav(){

    System.out.println("I'm here...");

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("toto");
    l.add("tata");
    l.add("titi");
    return l;
}
```

My forEach :

```
<c:forEach var="categorie" items="#{mainControleur.liQuickNav}">
    <h:outputLabel value="${categorie}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

My output stream :
I'm here...
I'm here...
I'm here...
I'm here...

As you can see "getLiQuickNav( )" is call 4times by my ForEach. But I just wan't to call "getLiQuickNav( )" one time...
How to call it just one time ?

Bonus question:
Why "getLiQuickNav( )" is call 4time whereas I have only 3item "tata,titi,toto" ?

Thank's

Answer (score 3):

You can't control the number of times that `getLiQuickNav()` is called - consider caching your list so it isn't rebuilt between calls.

```
private List<String> l;

public List<String> getLiQuickNav()
{
     if ( l == null )
     {
          System.out.println("I'm here...");

          l = new ArrayList<String>();
          l.add("toto");
          l.add("tata");
          l.add("titi");
     }
     return l;
}
```

As well you should be using `<ui:repeat/>` rather than `<c:forEach/>`.  See this [blog](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat) entry for why.

Comment: I don't think something like above is good practice in general. There is no reason for lazy initialization of something with 3 items. Construct the list in the constructor or a static block.

Comment: @GreenieMeanie - this is obviously a trivial example, chances are that the actual list data would *not* be available on object construction or static block initialization (i.e. if it was pulled from some external source such as a database).  The answer was meant to illustrate that constructing the list should not be done on every call to getLiQuickNav().

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

You're reinitializing the state in a getter every time.  That is meant to be an accessor, not a way to initialize state.  Don't create the list in getLiQuickNav, create in a constructor or setter.

## Bonus

The first time you call `getLiQuickNav()` you initialize the list, the reference to this list gets returned and stored in a scope to evaluate your expression (.liQuickNav) and then the `getLiQuickNav()` is called by convention 3 more times for each item in the list.

It should get called once if you return the *same* list every time.  You're returning a new one every time.

Answer (score 2):

Getter's in Java (in any context, to include for Faces Managed Beans) should not generate anything - they should just return a value. Create the list before hand and return it.